# WP loop with if else statement

Tags: jquery, wordpress, if-statement

I am working on a WP slider and want to use differnt animations based on the number of divs in the slider loop.  Below is what I have so far, it workes fine with just one if statment but I want to use multiple if statements.

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance for looking :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1}),

        slide1 = document.getElementById("slide1"),
        head1 = document.getElementById("head1"),
        sub1 = document.getElementById("sub1"),
        p1 = document.getElementById("p1"),

        slide2 = document.getElementById("slide2"),
        head2 = document.getElementById("head2"),
        sub2 = document.getElementById("sub2"),
        p2 = document.getElementById("p2"),

 n = jQuery("#slider div").length;

 if (n == 2) {
    tl.to(slide1, 1, {left:0 }, "slide10end")
    .from(head1, 1, {left:-1000}).to(head1, 1, {top:50}).to(head1, 1, {top:50}).to(head1, 1, {opacity:0})
    .to(sub1, 1, {right:-200}).to(sub1, 1, {rotation: 720}).to(sub1, 1, {opacity:0})
    .from(p1, 1, {scale:0}).to(p1, 1, {scale:1}).to(p1, 1, {scale:0})
    .to(slide1, 1, {left:-2000 }, "slide1end")

} 
else if (n == 3) {

    tl.to(slide1, 1, {left:0 }, "slide10end")
    .from(head1, 1, {left:-1000}).to(head1, 1, {top:50}).to(head1, 1, {top:50}).to(head1, 1, {opacity:0})
    .to(sub1, 1, {right:-200}).to(sub1, 1, {rotation: 720}).to(sub1, 1, {opacity:0})
    .from(p1, 1, {scale:0}).to(p1, 1, {scale:1}).to(p1, 1, {scale:0})
    .to(slide1, 1, {left:-2000 }, "slide1end")

    .to(slide2, 1, {left:0 })
    .from(head2, 1, {left:-1000}).to(head2, 1, {left:-1000, delay:1})
    .to(sub2, 1, {right:-200}).to(sub2, 1, {right:-2000, delay:1, opacity:0}).to(sub2, 3, {right:-2000}, "-=0.9")
    .from(p2, 1, {left:-2000, ease:Bounce.easeOut}).to(p2, 1, {opacity:0, delay:1})
    .to(slide2, 1, {left:-2000 }, "slide2end")


} 

else (n == 4) {


    //slider 3
    tl.to(slide3, 1, {left:0 })
    .from(head3, 1, {left:-1000}).to(head3, 1, {left:-1000, delay:1})
    .to(sub3, 1, {right:-200}).to(sub3, 1, {right:-2000, delay:1, opacity:0}).to(sub3, 3, {right:-2000}, "-=0.9")
    .from(p3, 1, {left:-2000, ease:Bounce.easeOut}).to(p3, 1, {opacity:0, delay:1})
    .to(slide3, 1, {left:-2000 }, "slide2end")
}
```

});

Comment: Can you show the working code in a `fiddle` or `jsbin`

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error at the last comparison: `} else (n == 4) {` is not a valid structure. Either you use another `if`, or remove the the parenthesis and the rest `} else {`

Comment: I have fixed the structure (cant believe I didn't notice that) the code in "else" is being used despite the div count being 3

Comment: If that's the case you have a broken js machine. Can you update your question with the modifications you made, and some `console.log` to see the value of `n`?